# Can I select just the first ten rows and also skip the first ten rows of a foreach?

Tags: c#

I am running a process like this:

```
foreach (var x in App.cardSetWithWordCount.Select((r, i) => 
      new { Row = r, Index = i }))
{
            // Some code here
}
```

The code inside this routine takes a long time and what I would like to do is to run this for the first ten rows and then run it again for the remaining rows. Something like this:

```
// just the first ten rows in App.cardSetWithWordCount
foreach (var x in App.cardSetWithWordCount.Select((r, i) => 
      new { Row = r, Index = i }))
{
            // Some code here
}
```

then

```
// everything else except ten rows in App.cardSetWithWordCount
foreach (var x in App.cardSetWithWordCount.Select((r, i) => 
      new { Row = r, Index = i }))
{
            // Some code here
}
```

Is there a way to select just the first ten rows and also a way to skip the first ten that I could apply to the foreach?

Comment: What have you tried so far ?

Comment: as far as i understand you can not do. if i understand correctly. You want to change the list during iteration?

Comment: you can add a where a Where() statement like  so `.Where(x => x.r <=10)`

Comment: Consider using MoreLINQ's `Segment`.

Comment: You also need to put a `.ToList()` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
App.cardSetWithWordCount.Take(10)
```

To get the first 10, and then

```
App.cardSetWithWordCount.Skip(10)
```

To skip the first ten

Or I guess you could do it the old fashioned way, iterating over App.cardSetWithWordCount with a for loop.